# SqlException time out on SQL Server 16G database that stores files

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, timeout, sqlexception

ok - I know it's bad move but we did eventually decided to save files into DB for convenience... Now the problems come.

We have a database called "XXX_DataStore" where we save uploaded files onto a table and we separate binary file data into a table called "FileData" so it will be used only when we need the data.

Each file is less than 60M (90% files are less than 1M ) , however it happens only from last week that when user uploads file that is larger than 50M, the system throws  "SqlException Timeout" sort of exception (ASP.NET app) - any files less than 50M  can be uploaded successfully?!

I've tried to increase the "Connection TimeOut" on sqlString in web.config and also the timeout for ASP.NET application request - none worked.

Any help on this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The connection timeout setting you have changed is not related to this at all; it is for how long the app will wait for SQL to respond to the initial connection attempt - not for time taken for actual transactions.

Comment: there's also a fact that we didn't see files larger than 40M from the database so I'm not sure whether the problem was always there and we just didn't realize it till last week?

Comment: you must locate the real problem here. Is because is read on the disk and have huge delay ? in this case maybe you have limited disk space, maybe you need defrag ? - Then you must see if the timeout comes from the page its self and not from sql, maybe this is a problem of the session ? And see the SqlCommand timeout and not the connection timeout.

Comment: You know that NTFS is also a database :) You can use and move the data on disk and avoid to have this huge database. So make a script, move them all back on disk, and change the code, this is the better solution.

Comment: Thank you very much - it seems we had server hardware problem which may caused the problem - I don't know how, but defrag solved the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout you need to increase is the SqlCommand timeout - this will default to 30 seconds.